# Good Actionscript or Flex website?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript

Just wondering if anyone know a good flex tutorial website besides Adobe. Appreciate the helps.

Comment: by Adobe u mean the free videotraining as well: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/videotraining/ ?

Comment: Yes. I went to that link before. Still looking for new ones. Thanks though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Tour de Flex](http://flex.org/tour)
[First Steps in Flex Screencasts](http://www.firststepsinflex.com)

Comment: Love it +1 to you. wish I could do multiply accepts for everyone who provides links here.

Comment: I forgot about your first steps site... was pretty helpful for me. Thanks for that BTW

Answer (score 3):

http://blog.flexexamples.com/

this is a great one with plenty of examples to reverse engineer

Comment: Love it +1 to you. wish I could do multiply accepts for everyone who provides links here.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked out The Flex Show?

For learning, check out our screencasts:

http://www.theflexshow.com/blog/index.cfm/Fifteen-Minutes-With-Flex

We also do audio interviews; but those aren't like tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of other things you can check out:

Flex Test Drive (It's Adobe, but it's new, so you may not have seen it--aimed at developers with experience in PHP, Java, ColdFusion.):

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/testdrive/

Also, InsideRIA from O'Reilly has a lot of resources.

Comment: Thanks man. There are lots of things to check out.